# Android VoIP cailling with ZRTP using linphone-android

Tags: android, encryption, voip, linphone, linphone-sdk

Hi I am working on an android VoIP application using [this](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android) library from `github`. The core purpose of this app is to provide secure `VoIP`. I wanted to know if there is a way that `[linphone-android][1]` provides out of the box security measures.

Since we'll be using `ZRTP` for the media encryption, I was wondering if:

1. anyone can point me out to the piece of code where I can put the encryption code or if it's already there then please point to me where I can see it so that I can better understand my project.
2. if anyone can point me in the right direction for VoIP with media encryption for android.